# TypeScript Union Question (using two objects)

Tags: typescript

```js
interface A {
  profile: string;
  name: string;
  c: number;
  d: number;
}

interface B {
  title: string;
  profile: string;
  a: number;
  b: number;
}

function abFunc(obj: B | A) {
  return obj.name || obj.title
}
```

Like the interface above, there is data A or B. The above data also have overlapping properties.

How should we define the type in the function below?

'A|B' is used, so only duplicate properties are available.

### error message

Property 'name' does not exist on type 'B | A'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'B'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to discriminate the union, for example with the operator `in` :

```
function abFunc(obj: B | A) {
  return 'name' in obj ? obj.name : obj.title
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIA5QD2MwANhAFzIDOYUoA5gNw7IhwC2lNdjLuCKiACuHAEbR%20yACZDREqCwC%20WLKEixEKAEKZWYYGHJVa9EM1YFiZbqb6s4c8ZNZinC5apjCQCA4RBkODEAMR8EAApCMQArKl0AHzQASj1cKAgwYShAgHJ2LlzkUGRomOQAflLYgDoClCoymoMjCCwlIA)

Comment: Thank you, bro
Can I ask you one more question?

router.post('/', authenticate, (req, res) => {}

I want to put the body in this authenticate middleware differently for each router.
What should I do in this case?


For example, Router A has a body of {email:string;password:string}

In B router, in body,
I want {text:string, userId:string} to be included, but I don't know what type to use.